# Excel VBA - Looping through a column of a filtered table to find a specific line with the needed cell

Tags: excel, vba

***I have an already filtered table here:***
[image]

I have a Long variable called Mintaszam. In this example, it's exact value is 13. I need this line: AA <= 13(variable) <= AB. Now that I have the exact line (the second one) I need to copy the contents of AJ from that line (it is a string and it's not on the picture) to an another worksheet.

UPDATE – I came up with an idea but the code is not working and I get no errors:

```
Sub leirasok_kozetkodokhoz_D_oszlop()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 46543

DoEvents

Dim Azonosito As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Reteg As Long
Dim Mintaszam As Long
'Dim B As Long
Dim D As Long
'Dim F As Long
Dim Reteg_leiras As String

Sheets("MINTA").Activate
'B = Range("B1").Offset(i, 0)
D = Range("D1").Offset(i, 0)
'F = Range("F1").Offset(i, 0)
If D > 0 And IsEmpty(Range("D1").Offset(i, 1)) Then
    Azonosito = Range("U1").Offset(i, 0)
    Reteg = Range("Y1").Offset(i, 0)
    Mintaszam = Range("X1").Offset(i, 0)
    Sheets("egyesitett").Activate
    With Sheets("egyesitett").ListObjects("_1").Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:=Azonosito
        .AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:=Reteg
        lastRow = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count - 1
    End With
    If lastRow > 0 Then
           Dim tbl As ListObject
           Dim rngTable As Range
           Dim rngArea As Range
           Dim rngRow As Range

           Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("_1")
           Set rngTable = tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

           For Each rngArea In rngTable.Areas

                 For Each rngRow In rngArea.Rows
                    'something is wrong here... 
                    If Mintaszam >= rngRow.Cells(26) And Mintaszam <= rngRow.Cells(27) Then
                    Reteg_leiras = rngRow.Cells(35)
                    Sheets("MINTA").Activate
                    Range("D1").Offset(i, 1) = Reteg_leiras
                    End If
                 Next
           Next
    End If
End If

Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAuto
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `Reteg_leiras = rngRow.Cells(35)`. Then run the code and let us know if the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: For one, in my newly created workbook cell AJ is column 36. And then, wouldn't a simple lookup (or binary search if the file is large) and copy be enough? Accurate cell selection is probably convoluted when using filtered tables, lookups should work no matter what.

Comment: Thanks @BenDot. AJ is column 36 indeed. I need to use two separate worksheets and check a lot of variables (borehole IDs, layer numbers, sample numbers etc) and then copy a few thousand cells – I don't think it's possible with a simple lookup.

Comment: @dev1998 Thank you, this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've figured out everything. This works:

```
Sub leirasok_kozetkodokhoz_D_oszlop()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 46543

DoEvents

Dim Azonosito As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Reteg As Long
Dim Mintaszam As Long
'Dim B As Long
Dim D As Long
'Dim F As Long
Dim Reteg_leiras As String

Sheets("MINTA").Activate
'B = Range("B1").Offset(i, 0)
D = Range("D1").Offset(i, 0)
'F = Range("F1").Offset(i, 0)
If D > 0 And IsEmpty(Range("D1").Offset(i, 1)) Then
    Azonosito = Range("U1").Offset(i, 0)
    Reteg = Range("Y1").Offset(i, 0)
    Mintaszam = Range("X1").Offset(i, 0)
    Sheets("egyesitett").Activate
    With Sheets("egyesitett").ListObjects("_1").Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:=Azonosito
        .AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:=Reteg
        lastRow = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
    End With
    If lastRow > 0 Then
        If Reteg > 0 Then
           Dim tbl As ListObject
           Dim rngTable As Range
           Dim rngArea As Range
           Dim rngRow As Range

           Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("_1")
           Set rngTable = tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

           For Each rngArea In rngTable.Areas

                 For Each rngRow In rngArea.Rows
                    If Mintaszam >= rngRow.Cells(27) And Mintaszam <= rngRow.Cells(28) Then
                    Reteg_leiras = rngRow.Cells(36)
                    Sheets("MINTA").Activate
                    Range("D1").Offset(i, 1) = Reteg_leiras
                    End If
                 Next
           Next
        Else
        Sheets("MINTA").Activate
        Range("D1").Offset(i, 1) = 111
        End If
    End If
End If

Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAuto
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```